# What is the relation between $\mathcal{G}_{12}, \mathcal{G}_{23}, \mathcal{G}_{13}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

please help me to find this.

Suppose that the number of group homomorphism from the group $G_1$ to $G_2$ is $\mathcal{G}_{12}$, from $G_2$ to $G_3$ it is $\mathcal{G}_{23}$ and from $G_1$ to $G_3$ it is $\mathcal{G}_{13}$.

Can we determine any relationship among $\mathcal{G}_{12}, \mathcal{G}_{23}, \mathcal{G}_{13}$ ?

I am stuck in it.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is composition: given $\varphi: G_1 \to G_2$ and $\psi: G_2 \to G_3$, we can form $\psi \circ \varphi: G_1 \to G_3$.  However, distinct pairs $(\varphi_1, \psi_1), (\varphi_2, \psi_2)$ may still have the same composite, i.e., $\psi_1 \circ \varphi_1 = \psi_2 \circ \varphi_2$, so I'm not sure this helps...

Comment: Where did this problem come from? Do you know anything else about these groups in this context?

Comment: The simple answer to your question is no.

Comment: @Dorebell sure. Let me make it clear. I was studying number of group homomorphisms. So far so many beautiful results I have got ( collected from books, research papers etc) . The thing is , not any common general formula I hv seen so far. So i was thinking what about this: derive some condition using which I can resolve this question using the known results already. thats why i asked the question. hope its clear.

Comment: I think the question is *way* too general. I wouldn't expect there to be any nice numerical relationship via the orders of the groups or anything like that in general, since it highly depends on the groups involved. (for example, there are Abelian groups of any order. There are also abundant nonabelian finite simple groups of various orders; however, there is no nontrivial map from a simple nonabelian group to an Abelian group!) I'd try to look for a much more specific context to work in. For example, it should be relatively easy to do it for finite abelian groups.

Comment: Cool. I will try that part. Thank you for your kind appreciation